# Maclaurin Series for $(\sec(x))^2$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, taylor-expansion

[Question 2a ii](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMC3k.png)

So I know I have to use the given tangent MacLaurin Series for solve for 2aii, but how did

$(\sec(x))^2 = 1+ (a_1x + a_3x^3 + a_5x^5 +....)^2 $

turn into
$ (\sec(x))^2= 1 + a_1^2x^2 + 2a_1a_3x^4 +....$ (Real Answer)

I thought it would be $a_1^2x^2 + a_3^2x^6$

Comment: What's the derivative of tangent?

Comment: First, is it $(sec(x))^2$, as you write in the body of your post or is it $sec(x^2)$ as in your title?

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
(a+b)^2 =a^2+ \color{red}{2ab}+b^2.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: "I thought it would be a1^2*x^2 + a3^2*x^6?"  Why would you think that?  (a+ b)^2= a^2+ 2ab+ b^2 NOT "a^2+ b^2".

Comment: @user247327 Well but $(a^2+b^2)=a^2+b^2+2ab$ as well. Also you might wanna make that argument with the expansion of $(a_1+a_2+...a_n)^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term $2a_1 a_3 x^4$ in (Real Answer) comes from $$(a_1x + a_3x^3 + ...)^2=(a_1x + a_3x^3 + ...)(a_1x + a_3x^3 + ...)=a_1^2 x^2+a_1x a_3x^3+a_3x^3a_1x+a_3^2 x^6=a_1^2 x^2+2a_1a_3x^4 +a_3^2 x^6$$

So what you computed is also a term in the Maclaurin series for $sec^2(x)$.

Comment: AHHHHHHHH!!!!!! Omg I see I see! Thank you! It makes so much sense now! Thank you

Comment: It says I can click the check mark after 3 minutes so Ill do it after 3 min Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. If, like me, you don't have the formula for $(a_1+ ... a_n)^m$ memorized, you would want to use the method I used in my answer quite often  when you're computing Maclaurin series, or in general, Taylor series.

Comment: !